# Multiple keycodes not working at the same time

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, xev, keycodes

I'm using xubuntu 14.04. I'm having a problem when pressing some keybinds (specifically with some keycodes). Thus, show you the result of `xev` when pressing first `Alt_R` and then `Alt_L`.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 1289711, (-144,-233), root:(446,267),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 1290931, (-144,-233), root:(446,267),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

My problem comes after this. The combination with some letters is not working. Let's say I keep pressed both `alt` keys, and then press `q`. Then following line should appear but it's not appearing at all:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 1711270, (14,-202), root:(608,272),
    state 0x8, keycode 24 (keysym 0x71, q), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (71) "q"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Nothing is being displayed with `q` (also with `e`, `t` and some others) and I would like to know why, because I use some of these key combinations for some keybindings in some programs.

Long story short. Some keybindings are not working because some combinations of keycodes are not working (it's keycode specific, I used other keyboard layouts to test it).

I also add you the information given by `setxkbmap -query`:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
```

Comment: Tried using other keyboards ?  I mean physical keyboards, not layouts.

Comment: the external keyboard works, so it should be a problem with the configuration (maybe in linux) of the keyboard of that laptop, but I don't know how to solve it (tested it with `xev` with an external keyboard). Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the output of  `xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'` and hit [R_Alt], then [L_Alt] and then close `xev`?  Also, add the output of `setxkbmap -query`?  Please [edit] your question and put the info there...

Comment: I added the output of `setxkbmap -query` to the description. As for the response of `xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'`. It's the following:
108 ISO_Level3_Shift ;
64 Alt_L

As I stated before, I have problems only with some keys, for example `[R_ALT]+[L_ALT]+q` is not working but `[R_ALT]+[L_ALT]+w` is working.